# Regex on two numbers and text, extract second number and text

Tags: c#, regex

I have text like the following:

```
Location # 06296 1829 GOLIAD RD.
```

i want to extract the second number and text. So I've tried this regex:

```
"(\d{2,})??[\w.\s]*\s+(RD)\s*"
```

i keep getting `06296 1829 GOLIAD RD`

I want `1829 GOLIAD RD`

How can i only get the numbers coming right before the text, not more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try out [this](https://regex101.com/r/EnK83L/1) expression:

```
(?<=Location # \d{5} )(\d*)\s(.*)
```

It gives you this result:

> Full match    17-32   `1829 GOLIAD RD.`
>
> Group 1.  17-21   `1829`
>
> Group 2.  22-32   `GOLIAD RD.`

This expression uses the positive lookahead expression to filter out the `Location #` part of the value, and gives you two result groups: the number of the string at the end of the line.

Comment: how about this - `(?<=Location # \d{5} ).*`

Comment: Might want to use `\d+` in case the first number isn't always 5 digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numbers before the text from you example, you could use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for what follows are characters, a whitespace or a dot until the end of the string.

[`\d+(?=[A-Z\s.]+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/MiN4kr/1)

- Match one or more numbers `\d+`
- A positive lookahead `(?=`
- Assert a character range for uppercase characters or whitespace or a dot one or more times `[A-Z\s.]+`
- Until the the end of the string `$`

Comment: this doesnt work, youself please check the URL given. Instead try this - `\d+(?=[A-Z\s.]+$).*`

Comment: @RohanKhude What does not work? Did you click the link?

Comment: Expected output - `1829 GOLIAD RD`. Your regex output `1829`

Comment: @RohanKhude "How can i only get the numbers coming right before the text, not more"